# what happens to unhandled exceptions in a website's javascript?

Tags: javascript

I recently had an exception occurring that I didn't notice till I looked at chrome dev tools console.

Does a website's javascript just handle and log exceptions at a higher level somewhere? I didn't handle the exception in function1 below, so the later functions were just not being run or something.

what exactly happens when an exception happens? I'm used to an unhandled exception meaning the program just stops

```
containingFunction
{
   function1();
   function2()
   function3()
   return;
}
```

Comment: Unhandled exception means that the *current execution* just stops. Whether or that affects the entire website will depend on how the application is structured and probably where the exception occurs.

Answer (score 9):

## TLDR

If an exception is not caught and is allowed to bubble up to global scope then the javascript engine will simply stop processing anything.

So it is not simply:

> later functions were just not being run or something

It is any code below the exception will not be run. Regardless of whether they are functions, `if` statements, loops etc.

## But.. events keep happening??

Well.. it depends.

To be more specific, the browser stops the **current execution of scripts** (1) and enter the [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). This means that any previous code that have managed to schedule events in the future before the exception will get that future callback executed.

For example, the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    setTimeout(() => console.log("ha"),1000);

    throw new Error("oops");

    console.log("ho");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Or if you are more used to looking at promise based code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("ha"));

    throw new Error("oops");

    console.log("ho");
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Will both throw an error and print "ha" but will **not** print "ho".

But this is dependent on the interpreter. The above is true for browsers but not node.js. Node simply exits the process on any uncaught errors.

For example the code:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log("ha"),1000);

throw new Error("oops");

console.log("ho");
```

Or if you are more used to looking at promise based code:

```
Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log("ha"));

throw new Error("oops");

console.log("ho");
```

Will **not** print "ha" nor "ho" when executed with node.

> (1) - By "scripts" I mean the script you wrote yourself as a web developer. Of course I don't mean any of the code that the browser developers wrote.

Comment: In browsers, I can go to the Developer Tools and execute code; so I can do just about anything after an error right? I haven't seen a browser shutdown after an error.

Comment: I was thinking that "reading from console" is also part of the event loop, so you can  interact with it even after a failure. But since it is doing *eval*, you can do anything after a failure which is slightly unusual in the normal context.

Comment: @Nishant - Not browser shutdown but script execution stopped. This is often called **broken** by people, as in "help, my javascript is *broken*"

Comment: @Nishant It is not the eval that allows the console to keep running but the fact that it has set up an "onchange" event or something similar to read the user input BEFORE the exception. See my `setTimeout` example

Comment: `and enter the event loop` nope it was already there if it was executing some js Maybe you meant *it will enter a new loop*, but even then that's not true, it will just stop the execution of the current task. You can very well have `Promise.resolve().then(()=>console.log('ha'));
throw new Error('han');` which won't exit the current event loop but still will log `"ha"`.

Comment: @Kaiido There is only ONE event loop. There is no such thing as a new loop. Imagine a while loop around the JS interpreter (indeed if you dig really deep down it is `while (select() ...)` or `while (epoll_wait() ...)` etc). What happens when an error happens is the current execution behaves as if there was a `break` statement in that loop and execution continues at the top of the loop. Normally for event loops we call this "entering the event loop" but in reality we are always inside the event loop. Only closing the window would exit that event loop

Comment: When I say "a new loop" and when specs talk about "entering the event loop" we all agree it's about  a new iteration of the looping system, i.e a loop. Nobody ever talks in terms of a programmatic while loop for instance because nobody says how things should be written. Now that semantic is fixed, no, throwing an error in js execution task does not break anything  in the event loop! That's just plain wrong, and what I thought was just a mislead phrasing actually exposes your incomprehension of how the event loop works on a browser.

Comment: As I exposed in my previous comment, microtasks that are pushed after the current execution on the same event loop do execute. All the other tasks that the browser has to do after the script execution will execute. When you  throw an error in js, only the current execution will halt.

Comment: @Kaiido I think you are just misunderstanding my words. You are saying exactly what I am saying. The loop is not exited - agreed? All scripts in the source file after the exception are not executed agreed? People often call this condition "broken" script agreed? Then I don't see where we disagree

Comment: @Kaiido I talk the way I do because I've implemented this before (I was a maintainer for a programming language called Ferite among other things and I wrote my own web server 3 times - once for fun, once because it was needed for a job and once as a node-stile async library for Ferite)

Comment: You say the loop iteration is broken; that's wrong. You seem to imply the loop iteration only consists in js execution that's wrong. We do not say the same thing at all. If it was true, then simply doing `const fn=()=>{requestAnimationFrame(fn); throw new Error('');}` would block the browser from rendering anything in the page! Because, in HTML, rendering is a part of the event loop.

Comment: I didn't say the loop iteration is broken. I said the script source file is broken because AFTER THIS LINE (where THIS is the line causing errors) no further lines of javascript IN THE FILE will be processed. All previous lines IN THE SOURCE FILE will continue to perform if they have scheduled some event. I explicitly said the browser will not be blocked but only your SCRIPT SOURCE FILE will stop executing after the line that cause the error. If you search questions on SO or just google around you will see people calling this condition as "script broken"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193865/discussion-between-slebetman-and-kaiido).

Answer (score 1):

When you construct your page you can place the JavaScript in the header tag or at the bottom of the page `(or anywhere in between for that matter)`. Some browsers execute the JavaScript only after the HTML and CSS is loaded, and some runs the JavaScript as it is being loaded.

A lot of people's html layout looks like this:

```
<html>
<header>
    <title></title>

    <!--Styles-->
    <!--End Styles-->
</header>
<body>
    <!--All content-->

    <!--End All content-->

    <!--Scripts-->
    <!--End Scripts-->
</body>
```

Reason being that the JavaScript doesn't delay the page load speed and if it breaks, most of the page is already loaded/rendered. When JavaScript breaks without a `try { } catch(err) { }`, the rest of it won't be executed but it doesn't throw errors on the page hence why the console exists in the developer tools (most browsers has this functionality)

[Read more here on w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)

JavaScript try catch:

```
try {
    //Do your work here
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
```

Comment: `Some browsers execute the JavaScript only after the HTML and CSS is loaded, and some runs the JavaScript as it is being loaded` -- this is not true. It depends on the browser, yes (currently all browsers after 2016 behave the same) but only because some older browsers don't handle the `async` keyword in the script tag. Browsers ALWAYS process scripts as they are encountered.

Comment: `Some` was the keyword. The OP didn't specify which browsers he/she is using.

Comment: You misunderstand my comment. "Some" is wrong. "Some if script tag is marked as async and not inline" is right. Without the "async" exception ALL (not some) browsers will execute scripts as they are encountered.